# Hard drive looks empty after CHKDSK

Tags: windows-8, data-recovery, chkdsk

My hard drive seem to have crashed, windows used scandisk on it for a long time. Now the disk appears empty, even though Windows claims that 200Gb are in use :

[image]

If I show system files, now I see the "found.000" folder, even though Windows won't let me open it :

[image]

In its properties it appears empty :

[image]

But when I use a tool like Recuva, I see that *something* is in D:/found.000 :

[image]

So, how do I get to those files ?

Comment: Why don't you just select the files then press "Recover". Of course you should recover those files on some other media because the disk in question, if written to, will reduce the possability to recover additional files. Your MFT on the disk is corrupt, MFT do not become corrupt, unless a hardware problem exists.  **Of course its already to late, you have already written data to those clusters more then likely, based on the screenshot.**

Comment: I added the Recuva screenshot to show that there were files under found.000; It's windows scandisk that has overwritten them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The files are there, since Recuva can "see" them. I was able to copy them elsewhere by booting into a Ubuntu live cd (http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)

[image]

Now all I need is to identify them all :)

Answer (score 0):

The solution I have used for this is to open the files with a binary or hex viewer, ascertain the file type, then open them with the corresponding application to see if the file is still functional. 
You can then save the file to it's previous directory (or another if preferred) and use it as before.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use recovery tools that can **ignore the MFT table**. It's `EasyRecovery Pro` or `R-Studio`. If you like to experiment do it yourself. But if you are still important details you should take your drive to a specialist center. And yes, do not check the built-in wheels. Turn off auto-check the disc `C:` and `D:` looks like:

```
CHKNTFS /X C: D:
```

See too:
[7 Ways To Recover CHK Files Created by CHKDSK and SCANDISK](http://www.raymond.cc/blog/how-to-recover-chk-files-created-by-chkdsk-and-scandisk/)

Comment: Why would he disable auto-check exactly?  Doing so won't recover his files...The disk clearly has problems if the MFT was corrupt and resulted in every single file's link being deleted.

Comment: @Ramhound Sometimes in the process of data recovery is necessary to reboot. Or is involuntary reboot. Auto-check can just finish the data.

Comment: The tool already ran, the links already deleted, and master file table deleted.  I agree with your statement its just sadly to late :-)

Comment: @Ramhound Update

Comment: "do not check the built-in wheels" --er, what ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`Chk-Back Chk File Recovery`](http://trcdatarecovery.com/software-apps/chk-back)  for this.

> Chk-Back is a Windows utility that can scan the content of a .chk file created by Microsoft Chkdsk and restore the original file type for many common file types.
>
> Chk-Back works by comparing the unique signature at the start of a file, known as the header, to an internal database of known file types.  This removes the necessity to use a hexadecimal editor or trial and error to retrieve files that have been damaged in this way.

[image]

Comment: I have a similar program to check the files once I'll have them. For the moment the problem is to simply read them.